# xamarin iOS equivalent for ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I need to save images in corresponding application memory in Xamarin.iOS and need to refer that image as image source for UIImageView.
 In UWP, I have created a folder and saved image sin ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. What is xamarin.iOS eauivalent for ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder?

Comment: Hope this will helps you. [Store User Cresdentials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058594/storing-and-retrieving-user-credentials-in-xamarin-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How to view the file saved in that location in device where it is deployed?

Comment: I'm afraid that in the device you will not be able to view it. In the simulator, you will be able to view it. In the device, you can check the path of the saved image using debug pointers for the confirmation.